# How use Facebook Graph API to list event invitations and declined events for user

Tags: events, facebook-graph-api

I have been trying to get list of event invitations sent to user. I played around with Graph API explorer found from

> https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer

I have tried calling https://graph.facebook.com/userid/events but it returns me only events user has responded to as 'attending' or 'unsure'.

Is it possible to get list of event invitations for user like displayed in Facebook event page.

Also I don't know how to list events user has responded as 'declined'.

Maybe I am missing proper permission but I doubt it since I gave all event related permissions to grap explorer and still got only 'attending' or 'unsure' RSVPt events.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can also do a GET on /{userid}/events/not_replied. It seems that Users that have not Joined the event will not show up in the /{userid}/events lists and if you look at the docs there is a subtle note there about only listing events that the user has joined. The old rest API seems to keep them in one list.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to HTTP Get the following from the Graph API:

`fql?q=SELECT uid,eid,rsvp_status FROM event_member WHERE uid = me()`

You can get back all three statuses from that call.

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "uid": "723020003",
      "eid": "19935786340002",
      "rsvp_status": "not_replied"
    },
    {
      "uid": "723020003",
      "eid": "234524000290351",
      "rsvp_status": "attending"
    },
    {
      "uid": "723020003",
      "eid": "210091000081240",
      "rsvp_status": "declined"
    }
  ]
}
```